# ¿cual es el equivalente al filestream de sql-server en mysql, o qué método hay en mysql que cumpla la misma funcion que hace filestream en sql-server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

buen dia, tengo una base de datos en SQL-Server con filestream donde todos los archivos se guardan en un contenedor fuera de la base de datos pero siguen conectados a esta, tengo la intencion de migrar a MySQL pero no he logrado identificar un metodo para que cumpla la funcion del filestream pero en MySQL. agradezco de antemano, espero no estar infringiendo ninguna ley del grupo puesto soy algo nuevo en la plataforma, gracias.

Comment: [SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) es un lenguaje, SQL-Server es un motor de base de datos, un producto comercial. Para MySQL revisa [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html).

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279381/do-we-have-any-file-table-file-stream-like-support-in-any-other-database-than) te ayude un poco